# Hackerearth practice problem not able to understand

Tags: algorithms, minimum-cuts

I am not able to understand below problem, mainly the example. I have tried to ask explanation in their website but not received help yet.

how they are calculating 36 and 43? and why 36+43 = 30$ is written?

Can I get a diagram visualizing this, because I think wood cutter should cost 12$ because only 3*4 area is needed.

**Practice Problem on HackerEarth:-**

Ad-optimization team is moving to their new office Safina Towers :) . But the problem is Safina towers don't have furniture, but you have wood-sheet. You are given a wood-sheet of length L . Since everyone wants to create their desk in their own style you have to give them some amount of wood. So, you are given N mark-down points (since ad-optimization team have n members) from that points you have to cut the wood sheet. But the problem is wood-cutter will cost (Xleft) + (Y right) for cutting the wood (where left and right is the size of the remaining parts of the wood after cutting). For example you want to cut a wood sheet of length 10 and X=3 and Y=4 and you want to cut at point 7 then left segment size = (7-1) =6 and right segment size = (10-7) = 3 then wood cutter will cost 36+43 = 30$ .

[Question Link](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/moving-to-new-office-dd532d09/description/#c126224)

Comment: What *is* your question?

Comment: how they are calculating 36 and 43? and why 36+43 = 30$ is written?

Comment: It's not 36 and 43. It should be $3\times6+4\times3$.  That's 30. Now can you figure where they got those numbers?

Comment: @RickDecker 
I believe you are right, I have edited the question so that I can understand it completely and code for it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Most simple explanation: The problem has been written down [*at hackerearth*](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/moving-to-new-office-dd532d09/) in some markup "language" not mastered by the author. Multiplication has been denoted using an asterisk `*` instead of a multiplication sign `×` (regrettably common since the introduction of type-writers). The markup seems to define that as a toggle between "normal" and "stand-out" text modes: there is a multiplication sign missing everywhere the text alternates between standard and italics. My stab at correction:

> Ad-optimization team is moving to their new office Safina Towers :).
>   But the problem is Safina towers don't have furniture:
>   You are given a wood-sheet of length *L*. Since everyone
>   wants to create their desk in their own style you have to give them
>   some amount of wood. So, you are given *N* mark-down points (since
>   ad-optimization team has *N* members). From that points you have to cut
>   the wood sheet. But the problem is wood-cutter will cost 
>   (X×*left*) + (Y×*right*) for cutting the wood (where *left* and *right* is
>   the size of the remaining parts of the wood after cutting).
>   For example you want to
>   cut a wood sheet of length 10 and X=3 and Y=4 and you want to cut at
>   point 7 then *left* segment size = (7-1) = 6 and *right* segment size =
>   (10-7) = 3 then wood cutter will cost 3×6+4×3 = 30.
>
> As Amazonian you have to follow frugality leadership principal, you
>   want to give wood cutter a minimum amount of money and want to cut
>   wood-sheet from every marking point between 1 to *L* (exclusive).
>   please note that in all the test case first mark point=1 and last mark
>   point = size of sheet (*L*). Please output minimum amount of money
>   needed for every test case.
>
> Input Format: T: number of test cases (1≤T≤5) For each test case:
>
> First line contains X and Y. (X: multiplier for *left* segment, Y:
>   multiplier for *right* segment)
>   2≤X≤100 2≤Y≤100
>
> Second line Contains N: Number of marking points (2≤*N*≤100)
>
> Third line contains marking point : m(0), m(1) … , m(n-1) marking
>   points on wood sheet, where m(0)=1, m(n-1)=*L* and 2≤*L*≤200000
>
> Output: For each test case : Minimum amount of money you have to pay
>   to wood cutter. Each test case answer must be printed on a new line.

Comment: Said author probably is as much a native speaker of English as I am.